# Continuing to receive an 'else' without 'if' error

Tags: java, if-statement, recursion, trace

The recursive calls are to be built up on the run-time stack and then the values are calculated in reverse order as the run-time stack “unwinds”. Line 18 is where I get the error but I'm drawing blank as to what is wrong. Compilation completed.  The following files were not compiled:
1 error found:
  [line: 18] }else{
Error: 'else' without 'if'

```
public class Recursion {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 7;
        //Test out the factorial 
        System.out.println(n + " factorial equals ");
        System.out.println(Recursion.factorial(n));
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static int factorial(int n) {
        int temp;
        System.out.println("Method call -- calculating Factorial of: " + n); 
        {
            int temp;
            if (n == 0) {
                return 1;
            }
        } else {
            temp = factorial(n - 1);
            System.out.println("Factorial of: " + (n - 1) + " is " + temp);
            return (temp * n);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is line number 24 ? and what is the error?

Answer (score 5):

You get that because your if statement is wapped in an extra block.

Change

```
{ 
  int temp; 
  if (n==0) 
  { 
    return 1; 
  } 
}
else
```

to

```
int temp; 
if (n==0) { 
    return 1; 
} else ...
```

You should also remove the extra declaration of `int temp;`. It appears twice in your `factorial` method.